# Looping through the result of App.Car.find()

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Assumed I have a model Car I could get all cars with

```
cars = App.Car.find()
```

How can I loop through all cars to change an attribute of each car (something like `cars.each do |car|` in Ruby)? For a single car I would do it with `car.set('colour', 'blue');` but I lack the JavaScript understanding to solve this trivial problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I loop through all cars to change an attribute of each car (something like cars.each do |car| in Ruby)?

The object returned by `App.Car.find()` is an Enumberable, so you can use the `Ember.Enumerable` API to access the child objects. So for example, you could:

```
cars.forEach(function(car) {
  car.set('colour', 'blue');
});
```

But in this case it would be more efficient to use the `setEach` method:

```
cars.setEach('colour', 'blue');
```

Enumberables API gives you lots of choices, see the  [ember enumerables guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/enumerables/) and [enumberables api doc](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Ember.Enumerable#setEach`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_setEach) for this:

```js
cars = App.Car.find();
cars.setEach('colour', 'le blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

If `find()` returns an array, you can use `Array.prototype.map` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
cars = cars.map(function (car) {
  return car.set('colour', 'blue');
});
```

There is also specific documentation for [mapping ember enumerables](http://emberjs.com/guides/enumerables/#toc_map).